# How to change the key of a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

How can I change the key of one nested dictionary?

For example, how can I change `data1`'s `"yes"` into `"no"` below:

```
dc = {'data1': {'yes': 'abc'}, 'data2': {'yes': 'xyz'}}
# CODES to get the result below:
dc = {'data1': {'no': 'abc'}, 'data2': {'yes': 'xyz'}}

dc[data1] = 'no'  # won't work.
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change a single dictionary just reference the dictionary you want to change.

```
>>> d = {'data1': {'yes': 'abc'}, 'data2': {'yes': 'xyz'}}
>>> d['data1']['no'] = d['data1'].pop('yes')
>>> d
{'data2': {'yes': 'xyz'}, 'data1': {'no': 'abc'}}
```

And if you want to change `yes` entries across all the dicts you have to a loop over [`dict.values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values).

```
>>> d = {'data1': {'yes': 'abc'}, 'data2': {'yes': 'xyz'}}
>>> for nested_d in d.values():
...     nested_d['no'] = nested_d.pop('yes')
...
>>> d
{'data1': {'no': 'abc'}, 'data2': {'no': 'xyz'}}
```

Comment: Note that this won't maintain the order of the keys.

Comment: @Mujtaba, In Python 3.7+, insertion orders are guaranteed. https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html